# How do you re-register routes for a specific user based on session varibales

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, url-routing

lets sey when my application starts up I register the following route:
website.com/slug -> page1.aspx

but how can i re-register that route like so:
website.com/slug ->page2.aspx

I know I can clear my RouteTable and Register my routes again, but this will mess up the routes for everyone on the site.

Is there a way to register new routes just for the specific user?

Comment: No (RouteTable Class: Stores the URL routes for an application)

Answer (score 1):

You'd like you can always write your own custom Route class that redirects users to particular area depending on their username/role membership... Although redirection could as well be part of your Login action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginCredentials user)
    {
        // authenticate
        ...
        if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
        {
            return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "User", new { area = "Admin" });
        }
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
    }

    This action assumes there's Admin area in your application.
    Custom route constraint
```

The other possibility is to have custom route constraints. So you would actually define two routes but one having a particular constraint:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Admin", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
        new { area = "Admin", controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { isAdmin = new AdminRouteConstraint() }
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
        new { controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
    );
```

This way you'd be able to route admins to admin area of your application and provide them with particular functionality they have there. But it doesn't bean that they need an admin area. That's just my route definition. You can define route defaults the way that you want.